# apostrophe cms data retrieval of join of pieces with join of another piece

Tags: apostrophe-cms

### **The code given below are the schema fields of a piece called home and home has pieces joined with it such as _trip, _accomodation, _testimonial.These joined pieces are again joined with other pieces in their schema.so on retrieving the home piece using api/v1/home the the inner joins of joined pieces are displayed as id.

## How do I get data of that id's???**

```
 {
      name: '_trip',
      label: 'Spotlight Trips',
      limit:4,
      type: 'joinByArray',
      withType: 'trip',
    },
    {
      name: '_accommodation',
      label: 'Spotlight Accommodations',
      type: 'joinByArray',
      withType: 'accommodation',
      limit:2,
    },
    {
      name: '_testimonial',
      label: 'Testimonials',
      type: 'joinByArray',
      withType: 'testimonial'
    },
```

The json given given below is a portion of the data retrived.I want to get the data of accommodation and trips  which is another piece , But instead here its id's are shown.

```
"_home-spotlight": [
        {
          "_id": "cki5owqrv008obgundta0x6rp",
          "published": true,
          "trash": false,
          "type": "home-spotlight",
          "title": "spotlightAbove",
          "tripIds": [
            "cki5oqi7r0063bgun81o6umqd"
          ],
          "accommodationIds": [
            "cki5owga1008mbgunlxweuera"
          ],
```

Comment: If you see `accommodationIds` there, by default you should probably also see `_accommodation` in the REST API response. You get both. Same for the other joins.

Comment: No I cant see it _home-spotlight is already a joined piece of home and the  home spotlight has joined joined pieces in it as trip and accomodation so that is shown only as id i need that data  @alexbea

Comment: Something might be missing from you description above. Do you have a piece called `home` that joins to another piece called `home-spotlight`, then `home-spotlight` joins to those other three piece types? And you are getting the `home` piece, but also want the data from the joined `home-spotlight` and any of those other three that are joined to `home-spotlight`?

Comment: yes this is my exact requirement  can you help me @alexbea

Comment: In normal use (not accessing via the REST APIs) you would use the `withJoins` array option documented here: https://docs.apostrophecms.org/reference/field-types/joinbyarray.html#settings. That would include the data for the subsequently joined documents. It is possible that the headless module doesn't support that option at the moment. Your short term solution could be to make the additional call using the IDs you have received. It would also be helpful if you would open an issue in the `apostrophe-headless` repo about this.

Comment: As a side note, the `apostrophe` tag in StackOverflow is about the English punctuation mark, so `apostrophe-cms` is enough for tagging.

Comment: ok will raise the issue and thank you for your  helpful information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, ApostropheCMS has no way to fetch contents from inner joins (that is, the collection joins has another collection joined) through Rest API. For now, we will get only the IDs of that collection. So as, alexbea said, we have to do an another additional API call to fetch that collection using the IDs.

Those who are not using Rest API can fetch these collections using `withJoins`
[https://docs.apostrophecms.org/reference/field-types/joinbyarray.html#settings].